# How to run Music Service in different process

Tags: android

I write a Streaming Music app, I work ok until I'm try to run the music Service in the different process. following the [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) of Android Developer, I've added the process of Service in the Manifest like here:

```
<service android:name=".MyPlayer"
            android:process=":myPlayer"
            android:enabled="true"/>
```

Then in the MainActivity I call the start Service:

```
if(_playIntent == null) {
            _playIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyPlayer.class);
            startService(_playIntent);
            bindService(_playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
```

The bindService will call to ServiceConnection:

```
MyPlayer _player;
private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MyPlayer.MusicBinder binder = (MyPlayer.MusicBinder)service; 
            _player = binder.getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isConnection = false;
        }
    };
```

Then the app stop working after this line:

```
MyPlayer.MusicBinder binder = (MyPlayer.MusicBinder)service;
```

The app show the message "Unfortunately, Mx Dance Music has stopped", Stack trace: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.xiKy.mxMusic.MyPlayer$MusicBinder at com.xiKy.mxMusic.MainActivity$3.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:356) at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1097)
                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1114)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4823)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    ClassLoader.loadClass:

The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

And then if I remove the line:

```
bindService(_playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The application isn't crash. How to fix this bug ? I'm appreciate any help from everybody.

Comment: "Find in the logcat I see the error" -- I am not aware that this is an error. "Then the app stop working after this line" -- please explain what "stop working" means. If your app is crashing, there will be a Java stack trace in LogCat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Edited, thank you alot CommonsWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyPlayer.MusicBinder binder = (MyPlayer.MusicBinder)service;
```

This works for local bound services only. Once you switch to a remote service:

- You need to define your API in [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)
- Your service needs to implement its `Binder` as a subclass of the `.Stub` class generated from that AIDL
- The client needs to use `asInterface()` to convert the `IBinder` into a client-side proxy generated from that AIDL

All of this is covered in [the documentation on AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare, you're awesome.